# Call child object in a list

Tags: c++, list, oop, pointers

I have a class named "block" that inheritance from a class named "MainObject".

Then I created a list and add "block". Also I use a iterator to loop;

```
std::list<MainObject> objList;

objList.push_back(block());
std::list<MainObject>::iterator p = objList.begin();
```

But when I loop thought the list I only can call the function of MainObject.
This is my Loop

```
for (p = objList.begin(); p != objList.end(); p++){
        p->Update();
}
```

Comment: When you're iterating over your `objList`, how would you know whether you're dealing with a `block` or a `MainObject`? If you want a list of blocks, why not declare your list as such? `std::list<block>`. You need to provide some more context.

Comment: That is because I want to add more objects types to the list. All object has a Update function that has to be called every frame.

Comment: Matt's answer below should do what you need. With the extra information in your recent comment, note that if `MainObject` has a **virtual** `Update` method, a cast is no longer needed, and you can just do `p->Update()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the storing the acctual MainObject in the list, not the inherited "Block" object. You should use the base pointer:

```
        std::list<MainObject* > objList;

        objList.push_back(new block());
        for (p = objList.begin(); p != objList.end(); p++){
          block* b = dynamic_cast<block*>(p);
          if (b)
          b->Update();
}
```

If using `std::list<MainObject>`,  `objList.push_back` will create a copy of the input parameter, and store a MainObject, not then inherited type, that's why you can only call functions of  MainObject.

But as the list stores the pointer of the base class, it should only call functions of the base. Casting it to the sub type and call the functions of the sub type is not a good design. The base class is like a contract, this kind behavior breaks the contract.

Comment: What happens if `*p` is not an instance of `block`?